# Pre-open nested collapsible with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to have my button collapsibles all already open when someone visits the page. They should be able to click any of the button elements to open/close the collapsible at any time.

The following is an example of code I'm working with right now. The children element opens automatically when you click on a closed parent button. What I need is to modify the code slightly so that all the button elements start as open.

```js
const collapsibles = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");
collapsibles.forEach(collapsible => {
    collapsible.addEventListener("click", function() {
        open(this);
        const children = this.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
        children.forEach(open);
    });
});

function open(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = element.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
        content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        content.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #0486C1;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #254062;
}

.collapsible::after {
  content: '\002B';
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

p {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Act 1</button>
<div class="content">
   <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 1</button>
   <div class="content">
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 2</button>
   <div class="content">
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a class `active` to all collapsibles initially

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible active">Snippet 1</button>
```

or you can make a script to open all collapsibles by default

```js
const collapsibles = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");
collapsibles.forEach(collapsible => {
    collapsible.addEventListener("click", function() {
        open(this);
        const children = this.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
        children.forEach(open);
    });
});

function open(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("active");
}

// here
document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible').forEach(open)
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #0486C1;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active,
.collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #254062;
}

.collapsible::after {
  content: '\002B';
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.collapsible.active::after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.collapsible + .content{
  display:none;
}
.collapsible.active + .content{
  display:block;
}
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #E2E2E2;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

p {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible">Act 1</button>
<div class="content">
   <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 1</button>
   <div class="content">
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="button" class="collapsible">Scene 2</button>
   <div class="content">
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 1</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 2</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="collapsible">Snippet 3</button>
      <div class="content">
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I changed you css a little bit and it now uses the `+` (sibling) selector of CSS to show all the `.content` after an open collapsible

Comment: Not sure how to add class `active` to individual buttons (doing <button class="collapsible active" type="button"> doesn't work). But the Javascript code for the overall code _does_ work, so thank you for that!